# How to launch an EC2 instance into a VPC with a public IP address in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-powershell

I have been trying to use the following script, but haven't been successful:

```powershell
$Ami=Get-EC2ImageByName WINDOWS_2012_BASE

New-EC2Instance -ImageId $Ami[0].ImageId -MinCount 1 -MaxCount 1 -KeyName uckey -InstanceType `
t1.micro -SubnetId subnet-56738b33 -AssociatePublicIp $true
```

The error is:

```powershell
New-EC2Instance : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-EC2Instance -ImageId $Ami[0].ImageId -MinCount 1 -MaxCount 1 -KeyName uckey  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...2InstanceCmdlet:NewEC2InstanceCmdlet)  
   [New-EC2Instance], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.NewEC2InstanceC 
   mdlet
```

---

The problem is about the parameter `-AssociatePublicIp` without it, the script works.

Thanks for reading

Comment: it seems there is no network traffic when i execute this script so the problem must be local

Comment: I can replicate it easily, so I don't think that it's a local problem, rather there seems to be something odd regarding the comparatively new `-AssociatePublicIp` parameter, because everything runs fine without, and adding it triggers the error you referenced. Also, performing the exact same operation with the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead is working just fine and yields the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and a possible workaround while still using PowerShell is to create the network interface first, and then associating it with the instance:

```
$subnetId = "subnet-56738b33"
$keyName = "uckey"
$instanceType = "t1.micro"

$Ami = Get-EC2ImageByName WINDOWS_2012_BASE
$ImageId = $Ami[0].ImageId

$networkInterface = New-EC2NetworkInterface -SubnetId $subnetId -Description "Primary network interface"

$interfaceSpec = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification -property @{"NetworkInterfaceId"=$networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceId}

$reservation = New-EC2Instance -ImageId $ImageId -MinCount 1 -MaxCount 1 -InstanceType $instanceType -KeyName $keyName -NetworkInterfaces $interfaceSpec
```

The InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification has a property to indicate if the interface needs a public IP address (see [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TEC2InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification_NET3_5.html))

Answer (score 5):

As of AWS PowerShell version 2.1.3.0, this bug has been corrected.

I was able to execute this script:

```
New-EC2Instance -ImageId $Ami[0].ImageId -MinCount 1 -MaxCount 1 -KeyName uckey -InstanceType `
t1.micro -SubnetId subnet-56738b33 -AssociatePublicIp $true
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this to be a bug in the [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/). As already [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830811/how-to-launch-an-ec2-instance-into-a-vpc-with-a-public-ip-in-powershell#comment36739724_23830811), running the semantically identical command with the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead yields the desired result:

```bash
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id $ami.Imageid --count 1:1 --instance-type t1.micro `
  --key-name uckey --subnet-id subnet-56738b33 --associate-public-ip-address
```

- Beware of the slight syntax difference for `--count` and `--associate-public-ip-address`, the latter doesn't require a value, rather comprises the flag in itself, i.e. `[--associate-public-ip-address | --no-associate-public-ip-address]`, see [run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html).

This is also confirmed by an (unfortunately unanswered) inquiry in the [AWS Forum for PowerShell scripting](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=149&start=0), see [Unable to get New-EC2Instance to honour -AssociatePublicIP](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=512653&#512653).

Accordingly, your best bet to get this resolved might be to bump that thread and hope for a response from the AWS team. Meanwhile you can work around the issue by means of scripting the operation via the AWS CLI instead.

Comment: thank you very much sir so i now know that there is no problem with my script but there is a problem with awspowershell i will report this isue